# Is $X_\tau$ measurable wrt $\mathcal F_\tau$? Even without any measurability assumption on $X_\infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space;
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $$\mathcal F_\infty:=\sigma(\mathcal F_t,t\ge0);$$
- $\tau$ be an $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$-stopping time on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space;
- $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$-progressive $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$;
- $X_\infty:\Omega\to E$.

Am I missing something or is $X_\infty$ always $\mathcal F_\tau$-measurable; without any measurability assumption on $X_\infty$?

In fact, this should be true, since $(\tau\wedge t)_{t\ge0}$ is $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$-adapted, we easily see that $(X_{\tau\wedge t})_{t\ge0}$ is $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$-adapted as well.

By introduction of $X_\infty$, $X_\infty$ is a well-defined function; even on $\{\tau=\infty\}$. And the former adaptedness result shows that $$\{X_\tau\in B\}\cap\{\tau\le t\}=\{X_{\tau\wedge t}\in B\}\cap\{\tau\le t\}\in\mathcal F_t\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag1$$ and hence $$\{X_\tau\in B\}\in\mathcal F_\tau\tag2$$ for all $B\in\mathcal E$.

(the natural assumption would clearly be that $X_\infty$ is $\mathcal F_\infty$-measurable, since then $(X_t)_{t\in[0,\:\infty]}$ is $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in[0,\:\infty]}$-adapted)

Comment: I don’t see any definition of $X_\infty$, what is it?

Comment: @Ilya It is defined in the list; it is a function $\Omega\to E$.

Comment: There it looks just like it’s any function. That’s your point? You’re asking whether any function will be $\mathcal F_\tau$-measurable? The answer is of course: no

Comment: No, I don't claim that any function is $\mathcal F_\tau$-measurable, but that it doesn't matter what $X_\infty$ is. However, I think I've noticed what my mistake was. See my comment below [John Dawkins' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4443262/47771).

Answer (score 1):

You have argued that the restriction of $X_\tau$ to $\{\tau<\infty\}$ is $\mathcal F_\tau\cap\{\tau<\infty\}$ measurable. But you have shown nothing about $X_\tau$ ($=X_\infty$) on $\{\tau=\infty\}$.

Comment: But $$\mathcal F_\tau=\{A\in\mathcal A:A\cap\{\tau\le t\}\in\mathcal F_t\text{ for all }t\ge0\}.$$ I guess the crucial thing I've missed is that I sitll need to verify $\{X_\tau\in B\}\in\mathcal A$ for all $B\in\mathcal E$, right? But wouldn't it then be enough to assume that $X_\infty$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable (instead of even $\mathcal F_\infty$-measurable)?

Comment: You need to verify that $\{X_\tau\in B\}\cap\{\tau=\infty\}$ is $\mathcal F_\infty$ measurable. That is, to show that $\{X_\infty\in B\}\cap\{\tau=\infty\}\in\mathcal F_\infty$.